# Xamarin Form Shell: Flyout v/s TabBar

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, tabs, flyout, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm confused by reading the [sentence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs)

> TabBar disables the Flyout

in the Xamarin documentation. But even the sample code shows TabBar in Flyout layout. I guess, I misunderstood the Flyout and TabBar (my idea is as per attached). Anyone kindly visualize the difference. Google search didn't give much on the TabBar, it just shows the standard documentation.

[image]

Comment: where are you reading this?  There are thousand of pages of documentation, can you please provide a link?

Comment: @Jason here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs

Comment: @Cfun Thank you for providing the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means if you use only `Tabbar` as a root element for your Shell, you will loose the `Flyout`, but if your root element is a `FlyoutItem` then you may benefit from both as in the picture you have shown.

From another side, you cannot explicitly nest a `FlyoutItem` inside of a `Tabbar` or the opposite.

When using a you can still define (`Tabbar`) bottom tabs but not explicitly:

```
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="First"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"/>

        <ShellContent Title="Seconde"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
```

In this example Page1 and Page2 will be displayed as **bottom tabs** AND as **flyout items**.

If for some reasons you want to display a page only as a bottom tab (hide it in the flyout), then you can set `FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"` on it `ShellContent`:

```
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="First"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"/>

        <ShellContent Title="Seconde" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
```

**EDIT**

Example of bottom and top tabs with flyout generated without the explicit Tabbar element

```
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
<Tab Title="1st Bottom Tab">
        <ShellContent Title="1st Top tab"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"/>

        <ShellContent Title="Seconde" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"/>
</Tab>

<Tab Title="2nd Bottom Tab">
        <ShellContent Title="First"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"/>

        <ShellContent Title="Seconde" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"/>
</Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
```

#### Conclusion

- If you want a flyout (independently whether it is in addition to tabs wither top or bottom or both) go with a `FlyoutItem` as a root Element (no need for Tabbar).
- if you don't want a flyout go with `Tabbar` as a root element.

Comment: So I was not mistaken, right ? The image I have marked is the same what Xamarin people meant. TabBar is the tabs show down, right ?

Comment: Whenever you see both a flyout and bottom tabs in the same view (providing only build in Shell component were used and not with another package) then it was done with a combinaison of FlyoutItem Tab and ShellContent)