# Xamarin.Forms new project dialog in VS 2019 does not have "Shell" template option

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, mobile-application, xamarin.forms.shell

I have looked through the existing posts and have not found one that addresses this issue.

I am trying my hand at Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 2019. I am trying to follow along with a couple of online videos and books, but am unable to because I do not see the same options on my system for creating the project as the tutorials have.

Specifically, the tutorials are beginning with a "Shell" template for the Mobile App project, and my screen does not have this option.

[image: tutorial]

[image: screen]

I am running on Windows 10 Pro; Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9.4; Xamarin Templates version 16.9.72 (426ebf6).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current **Flyout** and **Tabbed** template are in fact both based on `Shell`, they have replaced respectively the old **MasterDetail** (`FlyoutPage`) and **Tabbed** (`TabbedPage`) templates. I guess it a Xamarin.Forms team choice, to maybe encourage developers to move to the new Shell.

So if the tutorial you are following is using:

- The old **Tabbed template**, you need to select the **Blank** template and look at [TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page).
- The old **MasterDetail template**, you need to select the **Blank** template and look at [FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage).
- The old **Shell template**, you can choose either **Flyout** or **Tabbed** template.

The type `Shell` kind of combines both `FlyoutPage` and `TabbedPage`. If you are still confused take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/), also [Xamarin Form Shell: Flyout v/s TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66173044/5228202) may help.